# How to Generate CheckBoxes checked inside a DataGridView dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, checkbox, datagridview

There is a DataGridView that has a CheckBox Column. I'm generating the other columns of DataGridView from a table. It's working fine but now I'm trying some checkboxes to be checked using this code but it is not working. The code looks like

```
string query = "SELECT ID, Group_Name+' '+Phone_No as Info FROM Group_Info";
GenerateGridView(dataGridView1, query);

DataTable dt = GetTableData("SELECT Group_ID FROM tblGenerate");

foreach(DataRow rw in dt.Rows )
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)(row.Cells[0].Value );

        if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value) == Convert.ToInt32(rw["Group_ID"]))
        {
            chk.Value = chk.TrueValue;
        }
    }
}
```

How can we do this?

Comment: Probably you need to use chk.Checked = true should be used. However without complete code we can't able to answer.

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota the IDE is not showing the Checked Property of CheckBox.

Comment: Then it should have Selected property.

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota Still not working. The hidden code is generating tables from database nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May you try this:

```
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk);
            chk.HeaderText = "Check Data";
            chk.Name = "chk";
            dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[3].Value = true;
```